# Incompatible lang3 package error during maven plugin release for Springboot project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, maven-2, maven-plugin

I just downloaded the maven release plugin and attempts to configure my multi-module spring project to trigger an maven release. But I have obtain the following error when doing maven release:perform saying there is the following error about the lang3 library. I search other stackoverflow post and they said to use the latest version of lang3 library, I attempts that and it does not work, can someone give me some knowledge as to how to fix this?

The following is the error log on terminal:

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:3.0.0:jar (attach-javadocs) on project pet-clinic-data: Execution attach-javadocs of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:3.0.0:jar failed: Cannot invoke "org.apache.commons.lang3.JavaVersion.atLeast(org.apache.commons.lang3.JavaVersion)" because "org.apache.commons.lang3.SystemUtils.JAVA_SPECIFICATION_VERSION_AS_ENUM" is null

I have the following pom files for my multi-module project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>sfg-pet-clinic</artifactId>
        <groupId>guru.springframework</groupId>
        <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>pet-clinic-web</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>pet-clinic-data</artifactId>
            <groupId>guru.springframework</groupId>
            <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>sfg-pet-clinic</artifactId>
        <groupId>guru.springframework</groupId>
        <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>pet-clinic-data</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <spring-boot.repackage.skip>true</spring-boot.repackage.skip>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>sfg-pet-clinic</artifactId>
        <groupId>guru.springframework</groupId>
        <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>pet-clinic-web</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>pet-clinic-data</artifactId>
            <groupId>guru.springframework</groupId>
            <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is the full maven build output:

```
n1569231@LIBP45P-358886M sfg-pet-clinic % mvn release:perform   
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] sfg-pet-clinic                                                     [pom]
[INFO] pet-clinic-data                                                    [jar]
[INFO] pet-clinic-web                                                     [jar]
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------< guru.springframework:sfg-pet-clinic >-----------------
[INFO] Building sfg-pet-clinic 1.1-SNAPSHOT                               [1/3]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:perform (default-cli) @ sfg-pet-clinic ---
[INFO] Checking out the project to perform the release ...
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /Users/n1569231/Desktop/SpringExcercise/sfg-pet-clinic/target && git clone --branch sfg-pet-clinic-1.0 https://github.com/Jialin-Zhen_lmig/spring-pet-clinic.git /Users/n1569231/Desktop/SpringExcercise/sfg-pet-clinic/target/checkout
[INFO] Working directory: /Users/n1569231/Desktop/SpringExcercise/sfg-pet-clinic/target
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /var/folders/93/ns4g0g4s6wq14lvpl30wsg140000gp/T/ && git ls-remote https://github.com/Jialin-Zhen_lmig/spring-pet-clinic.git
[INFO] Working directory: /var/folders/93/ns4g0g4s6wq14lvpl30wsg140000gp/T
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /Users/n1569231/Desktop/SpringExcercise/sfg-pet-clinic/target/checkout && git fetch https://github.com/Jialin-Zhen_lmig/spring-pet-clinic.git
[INFO] Working directory: /Users/n1569231/Desktop/SpringExcercise/sfg-pet-clinic/target/checkout
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /Users/n1569231/Desktop/SpringExcercise/sfg-pet-clinic/target/checkout && git checkout sfg-pet-clinic-1.0
[INFO] Working directory: /Users/n1569231/Desktop/SpringExcercise/sfg-pet-clinic/target/checkout
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /Users/n1569231/Desktop/SpringExcercise/sfg-pet-clinic/target/checkout && git ls-files
[INFO] Working directory: /Users/n1569231/Desktop/SpringExcercise/sfg-pet-clinic/target/checkout
[INFO] Invoking perform goals in directory /Users/n1569231/Desktop/SpringExcercise/sfg-pet-clinic/target/checkout
[INFO] Executing goals 'install'...
[WARNING] Maven will be executed in interactive mode, but no input stream has been configured for this MavenInvoker instance.
[INFO] [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] sfg-pet-clinic                                                     [pom]
[INFO] [INFO] pet-clinic-data                                                    [jar]
[INFO] [INFO] pet-clinic-web                                                     [jar]
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] ----------------< guru.springframework:sfg-pet-clinic >-----------------
[INFO] [INFO] Building sfg-pet-clinic 1.0                                        [1/3]
[INFO] [INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:3.0.1:jar-no-fork (attach-sources) @ sfg-pet-clinic ---
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-javadoc-plugin:3.0.0:jar (attach-javadocs) @ sfg-pet-clinic ---
[INFO] [INFO] Not executing Javadoc as the project is not a Java classpath-capable package
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.3.RELEASE:repackage (default) @ sfg-pet-clinic ---
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ sfg-pet-clinic ---
[INFO] [INFO] Installing /Users/n1569231/Desktop/SpringExcercise/sfg-pet-clinic/target/checkout/pom.xml to /Users/n1569231/.m2/repository/guru/springframework/sfg-pet-clinic/1.0/sfg-pet-clinic-1.0.pom
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] ----------------< guru.springframework:pet-clinic-data >----------------
[INFO] [INFO] Building pet-clinic-data 1.0                                       [2/3]
[INFO] [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:resources (default-resources) @ pet-clinic-data ---
[INFO] [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/n1569231/Desktop/SpringExcercise/sfg-pet-clinic/target/checkout/pet-clinic-data/src/main/resources
[INFO] [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/n1569231/Desktop/SpringExcercise/sfg-pet-clinic/target/checkout/pet-clinic-data/src/main/resources
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ pet-clinic-data ---
[INFO] [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] [INFO] Compiling 5 source files to /Users/n1569231/Desktop/SpringExcercise/sfg-pet-clinic/target/checkout/pet-clinic-data/target/classes
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:testResources (default-testResources) @ pet-clinic-data ---
[INFO] [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/n1569231/Desktop/SpringExcercise/sfg-pet-clinic/target/checkout/pet-clinic-data/src/test/resources
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ pet-clinic-data ---
[INFO] [INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.21.0:test (default-test) @ pet-clinic-data ---
[INFO] [INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.0.2:jar (default-jar) @ pet-clinic-data ---
[INFO] [INFO] Building jar: /Users/n1569231/Desktop/SpringExcercise/sfg-pet-clinic/target/checkout/pet-clinic-data/target/pet-clinic-data-1.0.jar
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:3.0.1:jar-no-fork (attach-sources) @ pet-clinic-data ---
[INFO] [INFO] Building jar: /Users/n1569231/Desktop/SpringExcercise/sfg-pet-clinic/target/checkout/pet-clinic-data/target/pet-clinic-data-1.0-sources.jar
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-javadoc-plugin:3.0.0:jar (attach-javadocs) @ pet-clinic-data ---
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Reactor Summary for sfg-pet-clinic 1.0:
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] sfg-pet-clinic ..................................... SUCCESS [  1.018 s]
[INFO] [INFO] pet-clinic-data .................................... FAILURE [  1.246 s]
[INFO] [INFO] pet-clinic-web ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Total time:  2.417 s
[INFO] [INFO] Finished at: 2022-08-18T21:52:50-04:00
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:3.0.0:jar (attach-javadocs) on project pet-clinic-data: Execution attach-javadocs of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:3.0.0:jar failed: Cannot invoke "org.apache.commons.lang3.JavaVersion.atLeast(org.apache.commons.lang3.JavaVersion)" because "org.apache.commons.lang3.SystemUtils.JAVA_SPECIFICATION_VERSION_AS_ENUM" is null -> [Help 1]
[INFO] [ERROR] 
[INFO] [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[INFO] [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[INFO] [ERROR] 
[INFO] [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[INFO] [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
[INFO] [ERROR] 
[INFO] [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[INFO] [ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :pet-clinic-data
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for sfg-pet-clinic 1.1-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO] 
[INFO] sfg-pet-clinic ..................................... FAILURE [  6.504 s]
[INFO] pet-clinic-data .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] pet-clinic-web ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  6.705 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-08-18T21:52:50-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:perform (default-cli) on project sfg-pet-clinic: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1' -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
n1569231@LIBP45P-358886M sfg-pet-clinic % clear
n1569231@LIBP45P-358886M sfg-pet-clinic % mvn release:perform 
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] sfg-pet-clinic                                                     [pom]
[INFO] pet-clinic-data                                                    [jar]
[INFO] pet-clinic-web                                                     [jar]
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------< guru.springframework:sfg-pet-clinic >-----------------
[INFO] Building sfg-pet-clinic 1.1-SNAPSHOT                               [1/3]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:perform (default-cli) @ sfg-pet-clinic ---
[INFO] Checking out the project to perform the release ...
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /Users/n1569231/Desktop/SpringExcercise/sfg-pet-clinic/target && git clone --branch sfg-pet-clinic-1.0 https://github.com/Jialin-Zhen_lmig/spring-pet-clinic.git /Users/n1569231/Desktop/SpringExcercise/sfg-pet-clinic/target/checkout
[INFO] Working directory: /Users/n1569231/Desktop/SpringExcercise/sfg-pet-clinic/target
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /var/folders/93/ns4g0g4s6wq14lvpl30wsg140000gp/T/ && git ls-remote https://github.com/Jialin-Zhen_lmig/spring-pet-clinic.git
[INFO] Working directory: /var/folders/93/ns4g0g4s6wq14lvpl30wsg140000gp/T
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /Users/n1569231/Desktop/SpringExcercise/sfg-pet-clinic/target/checkout && git fetch https://github.com/Jialin-Zhen_lmig/spring-pet-clinic.git
[INFO] Working directory: /Users/n1569231/Desktop/SpringExcercise/sfg-pet-clinic/target/checkout
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /Users/n1569231/Desktop/SpringExcercise/sfg-pet-clinic/target/checkout && git checkout sfg-pet-clinic-1.0
[INFO] Working directory: /Users/n1569231/Desktop/SpringExcercise/sfg-pet-clinic/target/checkout
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /Users/n1569231/Desktop/SpringExcercise/sfg-pet-clinic/target/checkout && git ls-files
[INFO] Working directory: /Users/n1569231/Desktop/SpringExcercise/sfg-pet-clinic/target/checkout
[INFO] Invoking perform goals in directory /Users/n1569231/Desktop/SpringExcercise/sfg-pet-clinic/target/checkout
[INFO] Executing goals 'install'...
[WARNING] Maven will be executed in interactive mode, but no input stream has been configured for this MavenInvoker instance.
[INFO] [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] sfg-pet-clinic                                                     [pom]
[INFO] [INFO] pet-clinic-data                                                    [jar]
[INFO] [INFO] pet-clinic-web                                                     [jar]
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] ----------------< guru.springframework:sfg-pet-clinic >-----------------
[INFO] [INFO] Building sfg-pet-clinic 1.0                                        [1/3]
[INFO] [INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:3.0.1:jar-no-fork (attach-sources) @ sfg-pet-clinic ---
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-javadoc-plugin:3.0.0:jar (attach-javadocs) @ sfg-pet-clinic ---
[INFO] [INFO] Not executing Javadoc as the project is not a Java classpath-capable package
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.3.RELEASE:repackage (default) @ sfg-pet-clinic ---
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ sfg-pet-clinic ---
[INFO] [INFO] Installing /Users/n1569231/Desktop/SpringExcercise/sfg-pet-clinic/target/checkout/pom.xml to /Users/n1569231/.m2/repository/guru/springframework/sfg-pet-clinic/1.0/sfg-pet-clinic-1.0.pom
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] ----------------< guru.springframework:pet-clinic-data >----------------
[INFO] [INFO] Building pet-clinic-data 1.0                                       [2/3]
[INFO] [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:resources (default-resources) @ pet-clinic-data ---
[INFO] [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/n1569231/Desktop/SpringExcercise/sfg-pet-clinic/target/checkout/pet-clinic-data/src/main/resources
[INFO] [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/n1569231/Desktop/SpringExcercise/sfg-pet-clinic/target/checkout/pet-clinic-data/src/main/resources
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ pet-clinic-data ---
[INFO] [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] [INFO] Compiling 5 source files to /Users/n1569231/Desktop/SpringExcercise/sfg-pet-clinic/target/checkout/pet-clinic-data/target/classes
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:testResources (default-testResources) @ pet-clinic-data ---
[INFO] [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/n1569231/Desktop/SpringExcercise/sfg-pet-clinic/target/checkout/pet-clinic-data/src/test/resources
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ pet-clinic-data ---
[INFO] [INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.21.0:test (default-test) @ pet-clinic-data ---
[INFO] [INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.0.2:jar (default-jar) @ pet-clinic-data ---
[INFO] [INFO] Building jar: /Users/n1569231/Desktop/SpringExcercise/sfg-pet-clinic/target/checkout/pet-clinic-data/target/pet-clinic-data-1.0.jar
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:3.0.1:jar-no-fork (attach-sources) @ pet-clinic-data ---
[INFO] [INFO] Building jar: /Users/n1569231/Desktop/SpringExcercise/sfg-pet-clinic/target/checkout/pet-clinic-data/target/pet-clinic-data-1.0-sources.jar
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-javadoc-plugin:3.0.0:jar (attach-javadocs) @ pet-clinic-data ---
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Reactor Summary for sfg-pet-clinic 1.0:
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] sfg-pet-clinic ..................................... SUCCESS [  1.757 s]
[INFO] [INFO] pet-clinic-data .................................... FAILURE [  1.778 s]
[INFO] [INFO] pet-clinic-web ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Total time:  3.723 s
[INFO] [INFO] Finished at: 2022-08-19T09:05:40-04:00
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:3.0.0:jar (attach-javadocs) on project pet-clinic-data: Execution attach-javadocs of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:3.0.0:jar failed: Cannot invoke "org.apache.commons.lang3.JavaVersion.atLeast(org.apache.commons.lang3.JavaVersion)" because "org.apache.commons.lang3.SystemUtils.JAVA_SPECIFICATION_VERSION_AS_ENUM" is null -> [Help 1]
[INFO] [ERROR] 
[INFO] [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[INFO] [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[INFO] [ERROR] 
[INFO] [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[INFO] [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
[INFO] [ERROR] 
[INFO] [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[INFO] [ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :pet-clinic-data
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for sfg-pet-clinic 1.1-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO] 
[INFO] sfg-pet-clinic ..................................... FAILURE [  9.668 s]
[INFO] pet-clinic-data .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] pet-clinic-web ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  9.946 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-08-19T09:05:41-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:perform (default-cli) on project sfg-pet-clinic: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1' -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

The maven version using is 3.8.5, here is the output

```
n1569231@LIBP45P-358886M sfg-pet-clinic % mvn --v
Apache Maven 3.8.5 (3599d3414f046de2324203b78ddcf9b5e4388aa0)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.8.5/libexec
Java version: 17.0.2, vendor: Homebrew, runtime: /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/17.0.2/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "12.4", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
n1569231@LIBP45P-358886M sfg-pet-clinic %
```

Comment: Which Maven version do you use? Please show the full build output?

Comment: @khmarbaise I have edited the post, please review again. Thanks

Comment: Upgrade all the plugins you are using to the most recent ones https://maven.apache.org/plugins/ all the plugins you are using are more or less out of date... also use a more recent version of spring boot because 2.0.3.RELEASE is really old...nor supported anymore ... also it would be helpful to create a full working example on github or alike...